# Google Maps click on InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I am trying to call a function when user touches(clicks) on infoWindow. User scenario: User clicks on a google maps marker, an info window opens. User clicks on an item in infoWindow content. This click calls a function and another page opens. 
I am doing this in ionic 2 and typescript.

Here is the info window content :

```
text2 = text2 + '<div id="wrapper">' + '<div id="sidebar" >' + '<h5 onclick()=" '+ this.goToDealPage(businessDetails.deals[a])+ ' ">'+ businessDetails.deals[a].deal.title +'</h5></div>'+ '<div id="content"><h4 class="realprice"><del>'+ businessDetails.deals[a].deal.real_price + '</del></h4>' +'<h4 class="dealprice">'+ businessDetails.deals[a].deal.deal_price +'</h4></div>'+ '<br></div>';
```

What is happening now: When I click on the marker, this.goToDealPage(..) is directly called and the page opens immediately before clicking on infoWindow. I want it to be called when user click on infoWindow link not the marker itself.

Comment: Please include all code in `{ code brackets }` instead of an image.

Comment: Here it is. When I try to put this in the question window, this code gets lost. Thats why I had to send it as an image. { text2 = text2 + '<div id="wrapper">' + '<div id="sidebar" >' +
            '<h5 onclick()=" '+ this.goToDealPage(businessDetails.deals[a])+ ' ">'+ businessDetails.deals[a].deal.title +'</h5></div>'+
                '<div id="content"><h4 class="realprice"><del>'+ businessDetails.deals[a].deal.real_price + '</del></h4>'
                +'<h4 class="dealprice">'+ businessDetails.deals[a].deal.deal_price +'</h4></div>'+
              '<br></div>'; }

Comment: Use the buttons in the edit form. I'll fix it for you, but it's a good idea to read the help docs on how to post!

Comment: You could make you life a lot easier by using ES6 template strings

Comment: How you are attaching the click event on marker. There only the error is.